# Maze Solving in Python

Tags: python, solver, maze

I have tried tirelessly to make a maze solver in python. I have used all my resources such as friends, the internet, and stack. I have adapted my code a lot from stack questions previous to mine, but still can not come to an answer EVEN WHEN COMPLETELY COPYING CODE (which I don't like doing).

The maze/input file (nested list):

```
    [['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
    ['*', ' ', '*', ' ', '*'],
    ['*', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'],
    ['*', ' ', '*', ' ', 'E'],
    ['*', 'S', '*', '*', '*']]
```

This function keeps looping over the same points in the maze. My start point "S" is (4,1), with the output:

```
(4,1)
(4,0)
(3,1)
```

The above output is from the print statement I used to debug the function. It just prints the above in that order until it hits the recursive limit.Below is my solve function:

```
already_visited=[]
def solve(x,y):
    global already_visited
    matrix = draw(load())
    print (x,y)

    #base cases
    if matrix[x][y] == "E":
        for row in matrix:
            row = str(row)[1:-1]
            print row
        return True
    if matrix[x][y] == "*":
        return False
    if matrix[x][y] == "x":
        return False

    matrix[x][y] = "x"

    #---------------------
    if (x,y) in already_visited: #check if we have already been here
        return False

    already_visited.append((x,y)) #add position to list
    #---------------------


    # recursive cases (matrix traversal)
    if (x < len(matrix)-1 and solve1(x+1,y)):
        return True
    elif (y > 0 and solve1(x,y-1)):
        return True
    elif (x > 0 and solve1(x-1,y)):
        return True
    elif (y < len(matrix)-1 and solve1(x,y+1)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

All I am entering into the function for `x` and `y` are starting indices, S, as seen in the maze posted above. Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Wont Maze solver Code Work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545291/why-wont-maze-solver-code-work)

Comment: "which returns an indexing error at the if statement that contains the check for "E"" -- maybe that is because you didn't check `x < 0 or y < 0`. You can look at my answer on that post

Comment: What does `draw()` do?

Comment: It is not a duplicate, although I wish it were @cricket_007

Comment: I apologize @tynn , that just formats my maze from the text file it was read from! The return of "draw()" spits out the maze I showed in my question.

Comment: Please explain how it is not. The only things that are different are the symbols and your method names

Comment: `solve1(4, 1)` worked for me. So I'm not sure what your issue could be there.

Comment: @cricket_007 It is different because the error I am recieving is different. I am getting a loop of the same 3 positions being visited. I actually tried your exact code but got the same problem occuring.

Comment: @tynn could it be my compiler? would a computer restart/compiler restart help?

Comment: Short answer: `matrix = draw(load())` inside the function is the issue.

Comment: It isn't the problem that is important. It is the content of the question and the solution

Comment: @cricket_007 actually, a given solution is paired to a specific problem. That is the definition of a solution. Although a solution may answer multiple problems, your previous solution did not answer MY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the start of your function with the correct constraint check makes it work without running into the `IndexError`. First you need to assure that `x` is in range of your matrix row count. Then you need to check the same for the column count. Here the value given by `len()` is the first out of range.

Additionally your reloading the matrix in every call of the solver. You should only operate on one matrix to have persistent changes. For that add it as an argument to the function:

```
def solve2(matrix,x,y):
    print (x,y)
    if x >= len(matrix) or y >= len(matrix[x]):
        return False
    [...]
```

Then call it like `solve2(draw(load()),4,1)` on the first run and replace every recursing call with equivalents of `solve2(matrix,x,y-1))`. The same works for `solve1()` as well.

Comment: still getting the same three points being visited repeatedly. @tynn

Comment: If it works for you then I trust it works! I will work on my draw() and load() functions! They make up roughly 70 lines though and it would be silly for me to include them in my edit. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KyleClassen you don't really need to work on the `draw()` and `load()` methods. Just don't create the matrix in the scope of your functions for every recursion. With `matrix[x][y] = "x"` you're adding state to it you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

Making the maze is easy.  You make a grid first.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

G = nx.Graph()
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        G.add_node((i,j))
        if i >0:
            G.add_edge((i-1,j),(i,j))
        if j>0:
            G.add_edge((i,j),(i,j-1))
```

Then you delete the walls leaving the path nodes.

```
a = np.array([['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       ['*', ' ', '*', ' ', '*'],
       ['*', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'],
       ['*', ' ', '*', ' ', 'E'],
       ['*', 'S', '*', '*', '*']])

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if a[i][j]=='*':
            G.remove_node((i,j))
```

I'm cheating and putting in the start and end positions.  But then I have NetworkX find the path from start to end.

```
for point in nx.algorithms.astar_path(G,(4,1),(3,4)):
    print(point)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code here won't work:

```
if (x < len(matrix)-1 and solve1(x+1,y)):
        return True
    elif (y > 0 and solve1(x,y-1)):
        return True
    elif (x > 0 and solve1(x-1,y)):
        return True
    elif (y < len(matrix)-1 and solve1(x,y+1)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The Problem lies in the recursion. What your Program does is:

1. If possible go right
2. If not try up
3. If not try left
4. If not try down

Since you do it recursively, your program will go right till it hits a wall,

then go up till it hits a wall,

then left,

then down.

This makes it very easy to run in circles.

So you have two easy possibilities as far as I can see:

1. Remember if you have visited a location and always return False in the recursion IF you already have been here
2. Run randomly

Number 1 would look like this:

```
already_visited=[]
def solve1(x,y):
    global already_visited
    matrix = draw(load())
    print (x,y)

    #base cases
    if matrix[x][y] == "E":
        for row in matrix:
            row = str(row)[1:-1]
            print row
        return True
    if matrix[x][y] == "*":
        return False
    if matrix[x][y] == "x":
        return False

    matrix[x][y] = "x"

    #---------------------
    if (x,y) in already_visited: #check if we have already been here
        return False

    already_visited.append((x,y)) #add position to list
    #---------------------


    # recursive cases (matrix traversal)
    if (x < len(matrix)-1 and solve1(x+1,y)):
        return True
    elif (y > 0 and solve1(x,y-1)):
        return True
    elif (x > 0 and solve1(x-1,y)):
        return True
    elif (y < len(matrix)-1 and solve1(x,y+1)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Hello @JeD , your suggested ammendment makes sense and it's a good idea to keep track of previously visited spots! I am still having the problem with the function just visiting the same three spots recursively as seen in my question

Comment: I ammended the code in an edit